# border-bottom for <li> tag doesn't work in Firefox, but it does in all other browsers

Tags: css

Am I doing something wrong or does Firefox not support `border-bottom` property? I am trying to give `1px dotted` bottom border to `<li>` tag which works on all the browser but Firefox.

I am using CSS class for testimonials page. `list-style-image: url(../images/quote-left.png);` is used for open block-quotes and after the paragraph is over have quote-right to close the quotes.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="testimonial">
<ul>
    <li>testimonial 1. <img src="images/quote-right.png" /><br />
    <cite>-xxx</cite>
    </li></ul>
    <ul>
    <li>testimonial 2. <img src="images/quote-right.png" /><br />
    <cite>-xxx</cite>
    </li></ul>
    <ul>
    <li>testimonial 3. <img src="images/quote-right.png" /><br />
    <cite>-xxx</cite>
    </li></ul>
    <ul>
    <li>testimonial 4. <img src="images/quote-right.png" /><br />
    <cite>-xxx</cite>
    </li></ul>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```css
div .testimonial ul li {
    list-style-type: none;
    list-style-image: url(../images/quote-left.png);
    list-style-position: 0 0;
    font-family: Calibri, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 1em;
    line-height: 1.4em;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #000;
    border-bottom: 1 dotted #C0C0C0;
    padding: 0 0 20px 0;
    margin: 20px 0 0 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome btw to SO! If you're asking questions, it helps a lot if you show only the *relevant* code - this makes it much easier (and pleasant) for others to help you. Note that you can edit your questions at any time to improve them!

Comment: Thanks Jeroen. I updated/edit the my question if this helps.

Comment: The HTML layout seems strange to me.  What's the point of using the unordered list (`ul`) element if each one only contains a single list item (`li`)?  Why can't all `li`'s be inside a single `ul` as is usually expected?

Answer (score 0):

If this is for a menu you can get it to work by putting the styling on the `A`-tag (using `display:block`), not the `LI`. Also, use a CSS background, not list-style-image.

```
.testimonial ul, li {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

.testimonial a {
background-image: url(../images/quote-left.png);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
font-family: Calibri, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
text-align: left;
font-size: 1em;
line-height: 1.4em;
font-weight: normal;
color: #000;
border-bottom: 1 dotted #C0C0C0;
padding: 0 0 20px 0;
margin: 20px 0 0 0;
}
```

See my tutorial: http://preview.moveable.com/jm/ilovelists/

Answer (score 0):

At first it surprised me that Firefox can't figure out a default unit for the CSS rule because you didn't specify it on the width of the border. But, as mentioned in the comments (emphasis mine):

> It's *supposed* to dismiss the property as invalid if a unitless value isn't allowed there. If other browsers are assuming px, then the page is in quirks mode.

Try using this to fix your problem:

```
border-bottom: 1px dotted #C0C0C0;
```

Note the added `px` bit. Now the border-bottom will work in Firefox as well. See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h2qUY/3/) for a live demo.

Comment: awesome.. it worked. Cannot believe simple thing like px would give me a problem.

Comment: It's not supposed to figure that out. It's supposed to dismiss the property as invalid if a unitless value isn't allowed there. If other browsers are assuming `px`, then the page is in quirks mode.

Comment: Thanks @BoltClock, your comment makes sense, I've added it into my answer.